# Datagridview causing IndexOutOfRangeException when clicked upon

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview which we will call dataGridViewExample.

My object (the uncommon datatypes is because my database is SQLite):

```
class MyObject
{
    public Int64 Vnr { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Single Price { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
//This form gets called with a .ShowDialog(); in my form1.

private List<MyObjecte> ExampleList = new List<MyObject>();

public MyForm()
{
    dataGridViewExample.DataSource = OrdreInkøbsListe;
}


private void AddtoDataGridViewExample()
{
    //Add a new MyObject to the list
    ExampleList.Add(new myObject()
                 {
                     Vnr = newVnr,
                     Amount = newAmount,
                     Price = newPrice,
                     Name = newName
                 });

    //refresh datasource
    dataGridViewExample.DataSource = null;
    dataGridViewExample.Refresh();
    dataGridViewExample.DataSource = OrdreInkøbsListe;
    ddataGridViewExample.Refresh();
}
```

When MyForm gets called with a .ShowDialog, it shows up fine and displays my DataGridView example just fine. As you can read from the code, the `ExampleList`is initially empty, so it just shows an empty datagridview with 4 columns: Vnr, Name, Price & Amount. If I click inside it etc. nothing happens - so everything is working as planned, so far.

Everytime I call `AddtoDataGridViewExample()` it adds the new object to the Datagridview, and the datagridview does update, listing all the objects added so far (they show themself as rows, again according to plan).

Now, remember that I just said that nothing happened if you clicked inside `DataGridViewExample` before I have called `AddtoDataGridViewExample()`?
Well, after having called `AddtoDataGridViewExample()` once or more, the program will crash if I click inside `DataGridViewExample` (for example: the users wants to select a row). It throws an **IndexOutOfRangeException** and talks about an -1 index.
It also throws the exception in the other form, on the line where I call MyForm with `.ShowDialog()`;

I really am stuck on this, do you guys have any idea what is wrong?? 
**My only clue is** that I do believe the refresh of `DataGridViewExample`'s datasource might be the cause of the problem. 
Another **important** note: I have yet bound any events to my `DataGridViewExample`. So you can rule that idea out.

Here is all `DataGridViewExample`'s properties:

```
this.dataGridViewExample.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
this.dataGridViewExample.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
this.dataGridViewExample.AllowUserToResizeColumns = false;
this.dataGridViewExample.AllowUserToResizeRows = false;
this.dataGridViewExample.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
this.dataGridViewExample.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
this.dataGridViewExample.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(591, 53);
this.dataGridViewExample.MultiSelect = false;
this.dataGridViewExample.Name = "dataGridViewExample";
this.dataGridViewExample.ReadOnly = true;
this.dataGridViewExample.RowHeadersVisible = false;
this.dataGridViewExample.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
this.dataGridViewExample.ShowEditingIcon = false;
this.dataGridViewExample.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 150);
this.dataGridViewExample.TabIndex = 31;
```

Comment: Where is the code that handles the click event? Typically this exception occurs because you are handling a click event, and then trying to get the selected row when there is no row selected. Having a row selected, and clicking on the grid are mutually exclusive. So, where is the code that handles the click event that is throwing the exception?

Comment: I have yet added any events to dataGridViewExample, that is the alarming part :( so if anything, it is some inbuildt event which is causing it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I guess the click event tries to get the currently selected row and do something with it, while `dataGridViewExample.DataSource = null;` clears the datasource, and the currently selected row becomes null.

If you set the `DataGridView.DataSource` to the list, you don't need to reset it to null, refresh, and reset it to the list again (and refresh again) to see the changes. It will be enough to just refresh the `DataGridView`.

You can also just try using an `BindingList<T>` object instead of a `List<T>`, which will automatically notify your grid of its internal changes (Adding and removing elements), and there's also an `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface you can implement on your `MyObject` class, that will make every property change in an object show on the grid (For any changes made to the object in the code, and not through the grid itself).

Comment: This sounds extremely interesting. Could you show some code examples? Especially how to use the binding list and how I should call the refresh in my method

Comment: I changed the list to bindinglist, removed all refresh code and added a single refresh. Everything seems to work perfectly, Thank you so much!! A quick request though: could you show a code example of how to remove a certain object from the bindinglist?

Comment: In the event your data source can't be changed to BindingList, you can handle the `DataGridView.DataError` event and perform a `DataGridView.Refresh` within that subroutine.

It's a great alternative inspired by Noam's answer

Comment: Thanks. Also changing the list from a List<T> to a BindingList<T> solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the debugger and break when InedxOutOfRangeException is thrown to see where the exception is thrown?

Select Debug > Exceptions then there's a Find button on the dialog so you don't have to browse through all of the possibilities.

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work.  I have them all checked and when this happened to me visual studio broke out at the line where I called ShowDialog on the containing form.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation. I assigned generic list of certain object to DataGridView. Then I was setting null to DataSource and after that refresh. After that I assign list of objects to DataSource. While clicked on grid while runtime error occured IndexOutOfRange. My solution was to assign new empty list of my object to that grid and refresh and after changes on my working list I do assign to DataSource and call Refresh. Now, it is working without any crashes. Please look on my code before:

```
grid.DataSource = null;
grid.Refresh();
if(cases.Count() > 0)
{
   grid.DataSource = cases;
   grid.Refresh();
}
```

And now on my code after:

```
grid.DataSource = new List<MyCase>();
grid.Refresh();
//do something with cases
if(cases.Count() > 0)
{
   grid.DataSource = cases;
   grid.Refresh();
}
```